# Call to a member function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please, how do I resolve the following error?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
>   in......

**database.php**

```
protected function get_results_from_query() {
$this->open_connection();
$result = $this->conn->query($this->query);
while ($this->rows[] = $result->fetch_assoc());
$result->close();
$this->close_connection();
array_pop($this->rows);
}
```

**usuario.php**

```
public function getUsers(){
//$this->query variable define in class abstract database 
$this->query = " SELECT * FROM Usuario LIMIT 0, 30";
$this->get_results_from_query();
}
```

Everything is working perfect, but calling `function getUsers` results in "fatal error".

Comment: Add some debugging - your query is probably failing, but your code assumes that everything is fine. Check the return value from the `query()` call, and if it's false, echo out the error message from the database.

Comment: Just delete the question or flag it for closure.